# Forcing the order of many-to-many-field

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a score-keeping model for each player in a game, and a Match-model which uses the previous and compares them inside the game.

The 'p1' and 'p2'-fields are there only as controllers to identify when and where my problem occurs.
They get the user-id of board-user hardcoded when created. (and they are always created in an increasing order; p2 is **always** p1+1)

Problem:
Sometimes, rarely and what seemes to by totally at random, the order of the boards gets reversed.
Since i've been trying to find the source of this without success for some time now, i'd like to try a different approach.

Is there a way to force the order of the objects in the m2m-field?

Code:

**Models**:

```
class Scoreboard(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    score1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and so on...

---

```
   class Match(models.Model):
        pl1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        pl2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        boards = models.ManyToManyField(Scoreboard)
        active = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        turn = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I'm thinking something like this:

**views.py**

```
results = Match.objects.get(id=matchID)
boards = results.boards.all()
board1 = boards[0]
board2 = boards[1]

boardList.append(board1)
boardList.append(board2)


if boards[0].id>boards[1].id:
    print boardList
    boardList.reverse()
    print boardList

    m=Match(id=matchID, boards=boardList)
    m.save()
```

But this gives me an error:
   'boards' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2977145/853942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to define the sort order using a `through` class, which takes care of the original problem (untested, handle with care):

```
class ScoreBoard(models.Model):
    pass

class Match(models.Model):
    boards = models.ManyToManyField(ScoreBoard, through="MatchBoard")

class MatchBoard(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)
    board = models.ForeignKey(ScoreBoard)
    sortorder = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('sortorder', )
```